# exploade accosiative array type data

Tags: php

I have data like  following

```
string(133) "lindsey@testmail.com=>5.jpg,rickey@testmail.com=>6.jpg,darnell@testmail.com=>84.jpg,ball@gmail.com =>49.jpg,norton@tesing.com=>68.jpg"
```

i want to explode email and image separately.
i use explode but it didn't work.
i also try associative array.

here is my code but it didn't  work.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value ) {
echo $key;

    echo "<li><a href=\"".base_url().$keys."\"><img src=\"".base_url()."images/menters/".$values."\" class=\"img-border\"/><span>icon</span></a></li>\n";

}
```

i think it happen additional   string(133) 
i have no idea how to  accomplish this

Comment: some one put down vote  but they cant give hint even solve this at least comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with a single explode, you have to explode the string twice. You can then use an associative array to store values and use them

```
$array = explode(',' $string);
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
  $exp = explode('=>', $val);
  $assoc_array[$key]['mail'] = $exp[0];
  $assoc_array[$key]['img'] = $exp[1];
}

foreach ($assoc_array as $val) {
   echo 'Mail : ', $val['mail'], '<br>';
   echo 'Image : ', $val['img'];
}
```